# Prevent method override at runtime in Java

Tags: java, android

- Class A has method x()
- Class B inherits A and overrides x()
- Class C inherits B and overrides x()

I want to make a class lib that will extend Activity class and override the method that handles the back button in Android (and more methods). I want the developer to extend my class and keep using his activity class as usual, but to enforce him to call the method's super.

Any idea how can class B prevent its x method to be overridden **at runtime**?

(I don't want to finalize x in class B.)

### Update:

OK, let me try to explain what I want to achieve - I want to make a class lib that will extend Activity class and override the method that handles the back button in Android (and more methods). I want the developer to extend my class and keep using his activity class as usual, but to enforce him to call the method's super. If he won't do that, I'm in trouble.

Comment: So you want all the benefits of the `final` keyword without actually using it?

Comment: "I don't want to finalize x in class B" -- um, sure sounds like you do. What is the value in allowing overriding at compile time, if you don't want it overridden ever?

Comment: Kinda, I want to decide at runtime if I want to prevent C's x method from executing. I don't control C.

Comment: This is a problem that is easy to solve in C++, but the only way I can figure how to do this in Java is using some sort of code annotation using the java.lang.reflect package - and doing so feels to me like a hack.

Comment: You could try using AOP to insert code around calls to x and then include some logic to either call the C or B version.

Comment: David, I'd love to hear how you'd implement such behavior in Java.

Comment: Do I understand right that you wrote/control Class B, but someone else is extending your class by writing class C?

Comment: TJamesBoone, you're right.

Comment: @RonTesler then use the `final` modifier. If you don't want to use Java properly, don't use it at all.

Comment: @RonTesler perhaps you could give us some more context... otherwise it seems like a bit of a silly question i.e. "just use final"

Comment: How will you decide at run time whether it's allowed and what will happen if it's not?

Comment: What would happen if at runtime you find out that `C.x` is not allowed? Crash?

Comment: Thanks Legend. I'll send an apology letter to Sun.

Comment: I still fail to understand why you can't declare `B#x()` to be `final` and move on. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: To Oracle. You'd want to send it to Oracle.

Comment: Another question Ron -- is this in the context of a simple java application that runs from a main method, or is it something bigger like a maven project run on a server?  Because if it's the former I might have a hacky answer I can give you.

Comment: OK, let me try to explain what I want to achieve - I want to make a class lib that will extend Activity class and override the method that handles the back button in Android (and more methods). I want the developer to extend my class and keep using his activity class as usual, but to enforce him to call the method's super. If he won't do that, I'm in trouble.

Comment: So the developer is allowed to override your method as long as they call your version of it at some point?

Comment: Yes, but I can't enforce that, so I hoped there's a C approach to that matter :)

Comment: Do get to play with the final code or is this a library you export and never see again?

Comment: I'm writing a library

Answer (score 6):

> OK, let me try to explain what I want to achieve - I want to make a
>   class lib that will extend Activity class and override the method that
>   handles the back button in Android (and more methods). I want the
>   developer to extend my class and keep using his activity class as
>   usual, but to enforce him to call the method's super. If he won't do
>   that, I'm in trouble.

One solution is to make your method `final`, but have it call a second method which you declare as `abstract`.  Then make the other developer write the implementation for that `abstract` method.

So for example, your code might look like this:

```
public final void method() {
    // do your stuff
    // ...

    // call the method that the other developer wrote
    doMethod();
}

protected abstract void doMethod();
```

Whomever is adding functionality that must be called at the end of your method then *must* implement the abstract method in order to extend your class and have their code compile:

```
protected void doMethod() {
    // do more stuff
}
```

Then you would continue to call `method()` as you currently do.  (But keep in mind that this does not prevent someone else from calling `doMethod()` directly, so you'll still need to clearly document the API.)

Comment: Yes that's a good idea that I'll have to use if there's no other option...

Comment: I was starting to think along these lines as options for you... I'd go with Rob's answer.  I don't think there's any other that's as good.

Comment: This is a variation on the  Template method pattern and it's the usual way to go (the other is using AOP which is also ok). It's common (but not a rule!) in Java to call the abstract inherited method by the same name as the first method and prepend `do`. For example, if the first method was `play()`, the new one will be `doPlay()`. You've probably seen methods like this.

Comment: This sort of inversion of control is probably the correct approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your method in class B package protected and place class C in another package.

Comment: That's not a runtime solution, sorry...

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. The instance of B class will have it`s method. The instance of C class will have it`s own. You want the instance of C class to have the B`s method? You can try this with some kind of a decorator or a facade.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it suit your needs, but you can invent one more class, `D extends B` and then choose between instance of `D` and `C`, using some criteria. You can assemble `D` at run-time using reflection, so it will give result similar to following:

```
class A {
    void f() {System.out.println("A.f()");}
}

class B extends A {
    void f() {System.out.println("B.f()");}
}

class C extends B {
    void f() {System.out.println("C.f()");}
}

class D extends B {
    void f() {
        super.f();
    }
}

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a;

        boolean callC = false;
        if (callC) a = new C();
        else a = new D();

        a.f();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only control B, not C or D.

Comment: @RonTesler you mean that even the code which _creates_ subtypes of `A` is out of your control? Then only option is to have byte-code patched somehow...